# Why does the split() function in javascript work this way?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to understand how the split() function works in the below scenario:

```
'aaa'.split('a')
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
[ '', '', '', '' ]
```

Why do we get an array of size 4 with an empty string in each slot?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just like the empty set is part of every set, between every character there is an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Because you get

```
'aaa'.split('a')

""a""a""a""
```

but the pattern you split on is not retained

If you want to split a string into characters, use the empty string

```
'aaa'.split('')
```

or spread:

```
[...'aaa']
```

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

> The split() method divides a String into an ordered list of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and returns the array.  The division is done by searching for a pattern; where the pattern is provided as the first parameter in the method's call.